# Qemu - bind guest OS to secondary monitor without GUI on host

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, terminal, qemu

I am running arch distro with terminal only (without any GUI). I would like to start Qemu guest machine and bind it to a secondary monitor. Is this doable?